# Why is HTML5 video fullscreen making the whole page fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html5-video

I'm using HTML5 videos on our site. I've tried with plain HTML5 and with the Video.js plugin. Both of which, when you click the full screen button in the controls, make the entire page fullscreen but not the video.

I can't tell if it's something with my CSS, or some other bug. Does anyone have an idea why it's doing this?

Here's a link for an example: [example video](https://www.borrellassociates.com/industry-papers/webinar-theatre?vid=477)

Here is a code snippet for the video with video.js involved:

```
    <div class='twoThreeColumn'>
    <h3 class='current-video-title' style='color:#bbb;margin-bottom:5px;'>$title</h3>
        <video allowFullScreen='true' webkitallowfullscreen='true' mozallowfullscreen='true' width='auto' height='auto' id='webinar-$sku' controls poster='' class='video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered html5-video' preload='auto'>
            <source src='{$url}mp4/{$sku}.mp4' type='video/mp4'/>
            <source src='{$url}ogg/{$sku}.ogv' type='video/ogg'/>
            <source src='{$url}webm/{$sku}.webm' type='video/webm'/>
        </video>
</div>

<script>
    videojs('webinar-$sku',{},function(){});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide code snippets of the plugin.js of your video object.

Comment: Added my code snippet, was assuming you didn't mean for video.js to be pasted on here since that's a full plugin.

Comment: why can't you just use the video tag? it has built-in fullscreen capabilities without weird behavior...

Comment: " I've tried with plain HTML5 and with the Video.js plugin." .... Plain video tag is doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly why this is the issue, but I've figured it out it's due to the the div id that contains the video having the class "animated fadeInUp"... Removed both of those classes and it works fine.